# (Number Guessing Game GUI) Receiving same results with <elif> command (Python/Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am receiving the same results running an elif command.

This is a number guessing game (GUI Version) the aim of game is for the user to enter a number between 1-100. I am attempting to have a Tk.Label display if the user guessed to high to to low, using elif commands.

I have included the function that im having issues with, the output and the full code for the program in this post.

Function

```
def takeGuess():
    global wins
    global losses
    global tries
    global diceResult
    global rannum
    count = diceResult
    userGuess = int(enterGuess.get())
    while not count == 0:
        print(rannum)
        if userGuess == rannum:
            print("correct")
            wins += 1
            correctLabel = tk.Label(window,text="correct")
            correctLabel.pack()
            break

        elif count <= rannum:
                print("incorrect, you guessed to low")
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was:", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to low")
                incorrectLabel.pack()

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break

        elif count >= rannum:
                print("incorrect, you guessed to high")
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was: ", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to high")
                incorrectLabel.pack()

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break
```

Output

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "E:/Shanes Number Guessing Game (GUI).py"
August 31, 2020 13:29:11
44
incorrect, you guessed to low
1
the number was: 44
44
incorrect, you guessed to low
1
the number was: 44
```

Entire Code in full

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import time
import sys
import datetime
import os


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Shanes Number Guessing Game")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(bg='#74eb34')

# GUI Image
#logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Python-Tkinter pics\\numberguess.png")
#photo1 = tk.Label(image=logo)
#photo1.image = logo
#photo1.pack()

# score
tries = 0
wins = 0

# user enters their username
userNameLabel = tk.Label(window, text="please enter your name below", bg='#74eb34', font='bold')
userNameEntry = tk.Entry(window)
name = str(userNameEntry.get())
userNameLabel.pack()
userNameEntry.pack()

def HiName():
    HiNameLabel = tk.Label(window,text="Gday " + str(userNameEntry.get()) + "\n" + "I want to play a game" + "\n" + "roll the dice to get a number" + "\n" + "The computer will then guess a number between 1-100" + "\n" + "your dice number determines how many guesses you get" + "\n" + "lets play" , bg='#74eb34')
    HiNameLabel.pack()

HiNameButton = tk.Button(window,text="record name", command=HiName)
HiNameButton.pack()

# User enters their guess in a entry box
enterGuessLabel = tk.Label(window, text="enter guess below", bg='#74eb34', font='bold')
enterGuessLabel.pack()
enterGuess = tk.Entry(window, text=0)
enterGuess.pack()

diceResult = random.randrange(1, 6)


# Throw dice
def throwDice():
    global diceResult
    global tries

    print(diceResult)
    diceLabel = tk.Label(window, text="the number of your dice is: " + str(diceResult),font="bold", bg='#74eb34')
    diceLabel.pack()
    tries += diceResult


def takeGuess():
    global wins
    global losses
    global tries
    global diceResult
    global rannum
    count = diceResult
    userGuess = int(enterGuess.get())
    while not count == 0:
        print(rannum)
        if userGuess == rannum:
            print("correct")
            wins += 1
            correctLabel = tk.Label(window,text="correct")
            correctLabel.pack()
            break

        elif count <= rannum:
                print("incorrect, you guessed to low")
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was:", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to low")
                incorrectLabel.pack()

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break

        elif count >= rannum:
                print("incorrect, you guessed to high")
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was: ", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to high")
                incorrectLabel.pack()

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break

    # GUI Buttons


diceButton = tk.Button(window, text="roll dice", command=throwDice)
diceButton.pack()

guessButton = tk.Button(window, text="take guess", command=takeGuess)
inputGuess = guessButton
guessButton.pack()

rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)

# Timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp)


# open file
def file():
    os.system("statistics.txt")

def saveStats():
    with open("statistics.txt", "a") as output:
        output.write(str(userNameEntry.get()) + " played a game on: " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d") + " and got the results: " + "\n")


saveButton = tk.Button(window,text="Save Stats", command=saveStats)
saveButton.pack()

fileButton = tk.Button(window, text="open file", command=file)
fileButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `elif count <= rannum:` should be `elif userGuess < rannum:` and `elif count >= rannum:` should be `elif userGuess > rannum:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! At first your question confused me that such well written code had this bug that every time it is ran it always says that you guessed too low. You check your code..... You did a silly mistake there , see (instead of userGuess you have written count):

```
elif  userGuess < rannum:
            print("incorrect, you guessed to low")
            print(count - 1)
            print("the number was:", (rannum))
            incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to low")
            incorrectLabel.pack()

            tries += 1
            count -= 1

            break

elif  userGuess > rannum:

        print("incorrect, you guessed to high")
        print(count - 1)
        print("the number was: ", (rannum))
        incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to high")
        incorrectLabel.pack()

        tries += 1
        count -= 1

        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, my code was correct but I made an error with my variables

Incorrect

```
while not count == 0:
    print(rannum)
    if count== rannum:
```

Correct

```
while not count == 0:
    print(rannum)
    if userGuess == rannum:
```

Answer (score -1):

Improved your game a little bit :

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import time
import sys
import datetime
import os


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Shanes Number Guessing Game")
#window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(bg='#74eb34')

# GUI Image
#logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Python-Tkinter pics\\numberguess.png")
#photo1 = tk.Label(image=logo)
#photo1.image = logo
#photo1.pack()

# score
tries = 0
wins = 0

# user enters their username
userNameLabel = tk.Label(window, text="please enter your name below", bg='#74eb34', font='bold')
userNameEntry = tk.Entry(window)
name = str(userNameEntry.get())
userNameLabel.pack()
userNameEntry.pack()

def HiName():
    HiNameLabel = tk.Label(window,text="Gday " + str(userNameEntry.get()) + "\n" + "I want to play a game" + "\n" + "roll the dice to get a number" + "\n" + "The computer will then guess a number between 1-100" + "\n" + "your dice number determines how many guesses you get" + "\n" + "lets play" , bg='#74eb34')
    HiNameLabel.pack()

HiNameButton = tk.Button(window,text="record name", command=HiName)
HiNameButton.pack()

# User enters their guess in a entry box
enterGuessLabel = tk.Label(window, text="enter guess below", bg='#74eb34', font='bold')
enterGuessLabel.pack()
enterGuess = tk.Entry(window, text=0)
enterGuess.pack()

diceResult = random.randrange(1, 6)


# Throw dice
def throwDice():
    global diceResult
    global tries

    print(diceResult)
    diceLabel = tk.Label(window, text="the number of your dice is: " + str(diceResult),font="bold", bg='#74eb34')
    diceLabel.pack()
    tries += diceResult


def takeGuess():
    global wins
    global losses
    global tries
    global diceResult
    global rannum
    count = diceResult
    userGuess = int(enterGuess.get())
    while not count == 0:
        print(rannum)
        if userGuess == rannum:
            rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)
            print("correct")
            wins += 1
            correctLabel = tk.Label(window,text="correct")
            correctLabel.pack()
            break

        elif userGuess < rannum:
                print("incorrect, you guessed to low")
                rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was:", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to low ")
                lb = tk.Label(window, text = rannum).pack()
                incorrectLabel.pack()
                

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break

        elif userGuess > rannum:
        
                print("incorrect, you guessed to high")
                rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)
                print(count - 1)
                print("the number was: ", (rannum))
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(window, text="incorrect, you guessed to high ")
                lbd = tk.Label(window, text = rannum).pack()
                incorrectLabel.pack()

                tries += 1
                count -= 1

                break

    # GUI Buttons


diceButton = tk.Button(window, text="roll dice", command=throwDice)
diceButton.pack()

guessButton = tk.Button(window, text="take guess", command=takeGuess)
inputGuess = guessButton
guessButton.pack()

rannum = random.randrange(1, 100)

# Timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp)


# open file
def file():
    os.system("statistics.txt")

def saveStats():
    with open("statistics.txt", "a") as output:
        output.write(str(userNameEntry.get()) + " played a game on: " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d") + " and got the results: " + "\n")


saveButton = tk.Button(window,text="Save Stats", command=saveStats)
saveButton.pack()

fileButton = tk.Button(window, text="open file", command=file)
fileButton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.